# Given sets A,B, and C, express each of the following sets in terms of A, B, and C, using union, intersection, and set minus.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

having trouble with this one...

$F=\{x \mid x \in A \text{ and (} x \in B \implies x \in C \text{)} \}$

The only answer I can come up with is $A \cap(C-(C-B))$ but I don't think that's quite right...

Anyone have a better answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding $\{x:x\in B\to x\in C\}$ is a little tricky. It helps to remember that $\varphi\to\psi$ is logically equivalent to $\neg\varphi\lor\psi$, so

$$\{x:x\in B\to x\in C\}=\{x:x\notin B\text{ or }x\in C\}\;,$$

and that’s the union of two sets, $C$ and the complement of $B$. There’s a problem here, though: we’ve not been given any universal set in which all of this is taking place, so at first sight it may not be clear just what the complement of $B$ is in this context. Fortunately, we know that $F\subseteq A$, because every member of $F$ is required to belong to $A$ by the first part of the definition. Thus, the only objects not in $B$ that actually matter to us are the ones in $A$, and those are precisely the members of $A\setminus B$. Thus,

$$F=A\cap\big(C\cup(A\setminus B)\big)=(A\cap C)\cup\big(A\cap(A\setminus B)\big)=(A\cap C)\cup(A\setminus B)\;.$$

Alternatively, you could start by asking what elements of $A$ are **not** in $F$. If you do that, you get

$$F=A\setminus\{x:x\in B\text{ and }x\notin C\}=A\setminus(B\setminus C)\;,$$

and with a bit of work you can show that this is the same set.

Comment: Super thorough and helpful! Thanks Brian!

Comment: @BrianLilley: You’re welcome!

Comment: Why is this perfectly fine answer downvoted? This is so wrong to downvote for no reason

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to interpret $P \Rightarrow Q$ as Not$\,P$ or $Q$.

Thus, $F$ is all elements that are in $A$ and 
either (not in $B$ or in $C$).